# Softlayer API for ordering VMware licenses

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We want to implement automated vmware provisioning and as part of the process we need to order VMware licenses (ie vCenter) in an automated manner.

In http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/order-vmware-licenses it provides instructions on how to order licenses through SL portal.   I would like to see if this could be done via any SoftLayer API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it through [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method, here a rest request for it:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

Method: Post

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "packageId":301,
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":172249
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**Note**: Replace $user and $apiKey with your own information, also as you can see, the 172249 value refers to the license that you will place the order, to get all the Vmware licenses through API, try the following:

```
    https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/301/getItemPrices

Method: Get
```

The same idea could be applied in a programming language, to see available programming languages supported by SoftLayer:

- [SoftLayer Development Network](http://sldn.softlayer.com/)

**Some references**:

- [REST](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST)
- [SoftLayer_Product_Package](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)

Comment: Thanks Ruber.  I will give it a try!